# How do I create a link to a Sitefinity page in content via API?

Tags: c#, sitefinity

I am importing content from our old content management system. I'm trying to update the links located within the content (News article, Page control, etc.) to be Sitefinity-type links, linking to SF pages, news articles, etc. I've tried to recreate the structure of the anchor tag, including the sfref attribute, but publish doesn't remove the sfref attribute, and publish-and-sync doesn't update the URL to the new server. How can I properly do this with API?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is how you need to do this:

Let's say you have the following html from the old system:

```
Check our <a href="/about-us">About Us</a> page.
```

Now, let's say you have created the About Us page in Sitefinity.

You need to find the page node object (**sf_page_node** table) and get its:
**root_id** and the **id** values.
Let's say they look like this:

```
rootId: f669d9a7-009d-4d83-ddaa-000000000002
Id: b5d84f10-3660-42e4-b2c0-b89db2d6c884
```

Then the html snippet that needs to be saved to the database should be like this (tested in v.12.2)

```
Check our <a href="[f669d9a7-009d-4d83-ddaa-000000000002]b5d84f10-3660-42e4-b2c0-b89db2d6c884">About Us</a> page.
```

For images, let's say you have this in your html:

```
<img src="/images/image1.jpg">
```

I assume you have uploaded image1.jpg to Sitefinity and you know its Content_Id (from **sf_media_content** table).

Then you need to save the following html to the database:

```
<img src="[images|OpenAccessDataProvider]1dd75953-b4a8-46f6-93b9-6b29f5a62a04" data-displaymode="Original" alt="image1" title="image1.jpg">
```

Here I am assuming you use the default provider - **OpenAccessDataProvider** and that the content_id of the **LIVE** image is **1dd75953-b4a8-46f6-93b9-6b29f5a62a04**

Comment: Amazing. I was so close. I was writing out the actual URL to the href and src attributes, respectively, and writing the snippet as you describe to the "sfref" attribute--all because when I look at the source in the editor, that's what it shows. Writing that sfref value to the href/src attribute solved the issue. Thanks!

Comment: Yes, when the widget designers get the data from the db, they add the sfref attribute so they don’t loose the original value that was in src/href. Then when they save to the db, they copy the value of sfref to src/href. Glad it works now.